# Undefined variable: error - cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have this form validation i copied from a youtube video but it is coded using cakephp 1.3. so i'm having a hard time migrating it to 2.1

CommentsController.php - function validate_form()

```
function validate_form()
    {
        if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax())
        {
            $this->request->data['Comment'][$this->request['form']['field']] = $this->request['form']['value'];
            $this->Comment->set($this->request->data);
            if($this->Comment->validates())
            {
                $this->autorender = FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                $error = $this->validateErrors($this->Comment);
                $this->set('error', $error[$this->request->params['data']['field']]);
            }
        }
    }
```

validate_form.ctp

```
<?php echo $error; ?>
```

error:

```
Undefined variable: error [APP\View\Comments\validate_form.ctp, line 1]
```

how come it is undefined? please help me my boss gonna fire me if I didn't do this. I'm just a probationary employee a 5 days old junior web dev

Comment: Does it work if you replace `$this->autorender = FALSE;` with `$this->autoRender = FALSE;` ?
`

Comment: the error disappeared but there's still no output. -__-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your current code, `$error` is only set if the submitted form does not validate, but it is not set when the form does validate properly. You'll want to add a check to your view, prior to spitting it out, like:

```
if(isset($error)) {
    echo $error;
} else {
    echo "Form is valid"; // Optionally echo something else if everything went OK.
}
```

But this can't possibly be your entire view? This bit will only show the validation errors if any are present, but nothing else.

Comment: this is used $('$textbox').after(then here is the output). I applied this code and the code in the else is the only one appearing. I think the value of error isn't setting. how can i set it

Comment: As already stated, `$error` will only be set if the form contains errors, if the form is perfectly valid, it will not be set at all. Those "errors" should be specified as [validation set](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html) in the corresponding Model file. If you specifically want `$error` set either way, just put `$this->set('error', null);` in the if clause of your Controller.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that the comment is validating, so that's why `$error` is never being set, you just need to check for this in your view file:

```
if(isset($error)) {
    echo $error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to change this line of code:

```
$this->RequestHandler->isAjax()
```

to:

```
$this->request->is('ajax');
```

As AjaxHelper is depreciated from cakephp 2.x